# RaycastHit все возвращает true

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моей 3d игре на юнити я нажимаю на объекты, после чего происходит  какое-то действие. Для этого я определяю, что игрок смотрит на объект, что он достаточно близко, и что он нажал ЛКМ. Но если первое нажатие происходит без ошибок, то дальше для взаимодействия с объектом достаточно на него посмотреть, нажимать ЛКМ не нужно - это хочу исправить.

```
private Collider thisCollider; // коллайдер объекта, на который нажимаем
public int ActionNumber { get; private set; }

void Start ()
{
    thisCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && DoPlayerLookAtObject())
        ActionsList();
}

bool DoPlayerLookAtObject()
{
    int layerMask = 1 << 9; // игнорирую коллайдер игрока
    layerMask = ~layerMask;

    RaycastHit _hit;
    Ray _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));
    bool isHit = Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit, 2.0f, layerMask);        
    if (isHit && _hit.collider == thisCollider)
        return true; // здесь ошибка - все время возвращает true после первого нажатия на объект
    else
        return false;
}

public bool ActionsList()
{
    if (DoPlayerLookAtObject())
        switch (thisCollider.name)
        {
            // у каждого объекта, с которым взаимодействую, есть коллайдер,
            // уникальное имя и прикрепленный данный класс
            case "barthender":   ActionNumber = 1; return true;
            case "doorToStreet": ActionNumber = 2; return true;
            default: Debug.Log("Error: Out of range"); break;
        }
    return false;
}
```

К каждому объекту, с которым будет взаимодействие, прикрепляю верхний скрипт, а в другом классе проверяю, было-ли нажатие:

```
// для каждого объекта, на который будем нажимать, своя переменная
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoBarthender;
public OnMousePressCasino onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet;

// по номеру определяем, на какой объект ожидается нажатие
if (onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionNumber == 1 &&
    onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionsList())
    // do something

if (onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet.ActionNumber == 2 &&
    onMousePressCasinoDoorToStreet.ActionsList())
    // do something
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html Срабатывает при нажатии.  Слишком сложный у тебя код для обработки нажатия.  Или еще так https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: У тебя вообще не видно где обработка нажатия.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Здесь `if (onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionNumber == 1 && onMousePressCasinoBarthender.ActionsList())`

Comment: Это понятно. Где это вызывается? В какой функции?

Comment: @ValeraKvip Я в Update вызываю функцию, внутри которой находится switch (stepNumber), где stepNumber - номер текущего шага. Например, в начале он равен нулю и мы ждем, когда игрок нажмет на определенную кнопку. После нажатия stepNumber инкрементируется и мы ждем, когда игрок пройдет через триггер и т.п. Здесь более подробно, если интересно http://kozyr.org/2016/09/15/chronicles-of-cyberpunk-architecture/

Comment: Я к тому что в условии нет проверки на нажатие. Потому оно будет выполнятся при наведении всегда.  Убери это из апдейта и поставь в одну из функций на которые я выше дал  ссылки.